# Can Visual Studio Code update imports when moving MULTIPLE typescript files?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

(Answering my own question for visibility/searchability.)

When I move a single typescript file in VS Code, it updates the imports of the whole project. But, if I move more than one file at a time, it leaves the imports untouched, breaking everything.

Is this expected behavior or a bug? If the latter, is there a known fix? Is there a setting to updating imports of multiple files I have to turn on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/105110). There is [a PR waiting to be merged](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/105111). Until then, you have to move one file at a time.

Comment: Is it still a thing?

Comment: @IlyaKruchinin See this comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/105110#issuecomment-1720002068